# How to format the data retrieved from a database

Tags: java, html

Please help me to format the data retrieved from a DB. I want to retrieve data from a DB and display it in a webpage.
The database used here is postgres.
netbeans platform is used for developing web application.

I get the output as a single row

```
eg-SSN :1 Subbu TVM SSN :2 Kailas KZH
```

I want it in different rows

```
eg-
SSN :1 Subbu TVM 
SSN :2 Kailas KZH
```

my code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class view extends HttpServlet {
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
      throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
 out.println("<html>");
    out.println("<head><title>All Employees</title></head>");
    out.println("<body>");
    out.println("<center><h1>All Employees</h1>");
    String ls=System.getProperty("line.separator");
    Connection con = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    try {
      Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
      con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Project","postgres","1234");
      stmt = con.createStatement();


      ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM chef;");
      while (rs.next()) {
        String ssn = rs.getString("ssn");
        String cname = rs.getString("cname");
        String allocation = rs.getString("allocation");
        out.println("SSN :"+ssn+"  "+cname+"  "+allocation);

        //out.print("ssn : " + ssn +"\n" );
        //out.print("name : "+cname+"\n" );
        //out.print("allocation : "+allocation+"\n" );

      }
      rs.close();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
      out.println("An error occured while retrieving " + "all employees: " 
          + e.toString());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
      throw (new ServletException(e.toString()));
    } finally {
      try {
        if (stmt != null) {
          stmt.close();
        }
        if (con != null) {
          con.close();
        }
      } catch (SQLException ex) {
      }
    }
   out.println("</center>");
    out.println("</body>");
    out.println("</html>");
    out.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: Since you're producing HTML output, you will want to append `<br />` (the HTML newline operator) to each `println()` call.

Comment: `p`, `br`, `div` ... any HTML tag that give you a block. Of course you should not use that logic `out.println` but use at least a `jsp`. For those type of problem, always open the source code on the client side to see the actual result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Just use `<br/>`

`out.write("<br />");`

`out.write("SSN :"+ssn+"  "+cname+"  "+allocation);`

Comment: `println` won't help. You will have a nice html source code on multiple line ... that's all.

Comment: Yes ... because you've change the content ... _and_ != _or_. But the point is the same, `println` is not necessary. `br` is the only requirement for the HTML to show the new line